# how to use permissions table to fetch dynamic permissions for Sentry in Laravel 4

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4, cartalyst-sentry

I want to create dynamic permissions for each users through checkbox using Sentry in Laravel 4. 
I've created a table named `permissions` that has two columns:

`id            | name          | user_id`

Now, I want to use:

```
Sentry::hasAccess('any_permission_name')
```

But this `'any_permission_name'` should come from `permissions` table.

I've extend the `SentrUserModel` in my `User` model and add this relation to the User model:

```
    public function permission(){
        return $this->hasMany('Permission');
}
```

Now, I don't understand how to use Sentry with different `permissions` table for fetching the permissions.
Is there any way to use Sentry for this?

Comment: Why do you want to create separate table for this? Sentry provides JSON permissions already.

Comment: I want to create dynamic permissions. Thus, from admin panel, when an admin create a user, he should get all the permissions that is stored in the permissions table and decide which access the user should get. 
And an admin can create new permissions from panel.

Comment: Yeah, let me rephrase my comment - why would you store users' permissions in separate table? First of all it won't be `hasMany`, but rather `belongsToMany`, second you should just create table with permissions, and store them in the users table as JSON, the way Sentry does it. Use that table just as a collection of available options.